# How to select all element a under the class Menu in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I hope to select all element `a` under the class `Menu`, I use the code

```
$("Menu > a").removeClass();
```

but none is selected, how can I do that ? thanks!

```
  <div id="tabs" class="ShortWidth">
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#tabs-1">Internal Storage</a></li>
               <li><a href="#tabs-2">External Storage</a></li>              
           </ul>

           <div id="tabs-1" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
              <div class="Menu" >
                <a id="index0" href="index.htm?disk=0" class="MenuItem">My Image</a>
                <a id="music0" href="music.htm?disk=0" class="MenuItem">My Music</a>
                <a id="video0" href="video.htm" class="MenuItem">My Video</a>
                <a id="allfile0" href="allfile.htm" class="MenuItem">All File</a>
                <a id="search0" href="search.htm" class="MenuItemSelected">Search</a>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div id="tabs-2" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
              <div class="Menu" >
                <a id="index1" href="index.htm?disk=0" class="MenuItem">My Image</a>
                <a id="music1" href="music.htm?disk=0" class="MenuItem">My Music</a>
                <a id="video1" href="video.htm" class="MenuItem">My Video</a>
                <a id="allfile1" href="allfile.htm" class="MenuItem">All File</a>
                <a id="search1" href="search.htm" class="MenuItemSelected">Search</a>  
              </div>
           </div>         

       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

```
$("#selectorQuery").removeClass("classToRemove")
```

In your example:

```
$('.Menu a').removeClass("MenuItem");
```